# Type error while uploading file using formData

Tags: javascript, typescript, multipartform-data, form-data

The error message that I receive in the `value` part of `formData.append(key, value);`:

> Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'string | Blob'.   Type '{}' is missing the following properties from
> type 'Blob': size, type, arrayBuffer, slice, and 2 more.

Code

```js
const uploadSubtitle = async e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const file = fileInput.current.files[0];
            const res = await Axios.get(`/api/movies/${currentMovie.movieId}/subtitles?user=${user.id}`);
            const { url, fields } = res.data;
            const newUrl = `https://${url.split('/')[3]}.s3.amazonaws.com`;
            const formData = new FormData();
            const formArray = Object.entries({ ...fields, file });
            formArray.forEach(([key, value]) => {
                formData.append(key, value);
            });
           //... further code
    };


<form onSubmit={uploadSubtitle}>
   <input type='file' name='subtitle' ref={fileInput} accept='.srt' />
   <button onClick={uploadSubtitle}>Upload</button>
</form>
```

Additional details

`console.log(file)` gives

```js
File 
{name: "Trainspotting-English.srt", lastModified: 1587840529000, 
lastModifiedDate: Sun Apr 26 2020 00:18:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), 
webkitRelativePath: "", size: 103040, …}

lastModified: 1587840529000 lastModifiedDate: Sun Apr 26 2020 00:18:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) 
{} name: "Trainspotting-English.srt" size: 103040 
type: "application/x-subrip" webkitRelativePath: "" __proto__: File
```

`console.log(typeof file)` gives
`object`

Comment: Have you tried casting `file`, or calling `new Blob` on it?

Comment: @ZacAnger, I tried this.. `const blob = new Blob([fileInput.current.files[0]])` and then this `const formArray = Object.entries({ ...fields, file: blob });`, still it gives me same error

Comment: one thing that I would like to add is I am able to successfully upload files during developments...its just the typescript error that's causing the problem

Comment: Yeah, the error is coming from TypeScript, so you just need to figure out the right way to trick it into being happy. a `// @ts-ignore` comment would work but it'd be better to figure out what it wants. Asserting that `value` is `any` would also work: `formData.append(key, value as any)`, or `const file = fileInput.current.files[0] as Blob`  maybe.

Comment: the former one works i.e. doesn't complains about type error but the later doesn't...still I was wondering whether `console.log(file)` should already be Blob since the `__proto__` is `File` of `file`.

Answer (score 5):

It all comes down to the unknown type of `res`, introduced here:

```
const res = await Axios.get(`/api/movies/${currentMovie.movieId}/subtitles?user=${user.id}`);
```

`res` is `any`, which makes `fields` type `any`, which in turn makes `formArray` be of type `[string, unknown][]`, thus `value` is `unknown`, which causes the error.

To solve this problem at the source, we can use a generic type on the `Axios.get` method like so:

```
const res = await Axios.get<{url :string, fields: {[key:string]:string}}>(`/api/movies/xxx/subtitles?user=xxx`);
```

This will make `res` be of type `{url :string, fields: {[key:string]:string}}`. This causes `fields` to be of type `{[key:string]:string}`.

Unfortunately the spread operator does not infer the right types. The code `{...fields, file}` resolves to type `{file: File}`, which is not really helpful. So let's hint `formArray`:

```
const formArray : [string, string|File][] = Object.entries({...fields, file});
```

Now `value` will be of type `string|File`.

Full example:

```
function App() {

    let fileInput = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    const uploadSubtitle = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const file = fileInput.current!.files![0];
        const res = await Axios.get<{ url: string, fields: { [key: string]: string } }>(`/api/movies/xxx/subtitles?user=xxx`);
        const {url, fields} = res.data;
        const formData = new FormData();
        const formArray: [string, string | File][] = Object.entries({...fields, file});
        formArray.forEach(([key, value]) => {
            formData.append(key, value);
        });
    };
    return <form onSubmit={uploadSubtitle}>
        <input type='file' name='subtitle' ref={fileInput} accept='.srt'/>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
}
```

---

This is all rather a lot of work for something that can be fixed by changing the problematic line to:

```
formData.append(key, value as Blob);
```

Adding the `as Blob` won't change the compiled JS but will make the typescript compiler stop complaining.

Comment: ```value as Blob``` helped me. But I got ```Conversion of type 'number' to type 'Blob' may be a mistake``` error, so I did ```value as unknown as Blob```

Answer (score 0):

I had File data as { name: '', type: '', uri: ''} which was giving the error: Argument of type 'FileData' is not assignable to parameter of type String or Blob

So I did the following:

form.append('file', value as {} as Blob);
TS stopped complaining.